# Error message about 'libsqlite3' when activate environment in jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I try to activate my env to Jupyter notebook by using:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name native --display-name "python-gpu"
```

But error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.core.application import (
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/nianhua/opt/anaconda3/envs/native/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

It seems like something is wrong with my `libsqlite3`, but it goes well in my terminal.
My laptop is a Macbook pro with M1Pro. And I'm building an arm64 python environment in M1 version Anaconda.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: I still can not solve it, but I find there is nothing wrong with my env, because I can use it in Vscode. But `jupyter notebook` still can't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by installing a newer version:

> mamba install sqlite=3.40.0

always checking that the new library is coming from conda-forge/osx-arm64.